# PostgreSQL COPY FROM STDIN not working, but FROM PATH works

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, cat

In PostgreSQL I previously created a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stock_data (
  code varchar,
  date date,
  open decimal,
  high decimal,
  low decimal,
  close decimal,
  volume decimal,
  UNIQUE (code, date)
);
```

The idea is to import multiple csv files into this table. My approach is to use COPY ... FROM STDIN instead of COPY ... FROM '/path/to/file', as I want to be able to `cat` from the shell multiple csv files and pipe them to the sql script. The sql script to accomplish this currently looks like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stock_data_tmp (
  code varchar,
  ddate varchar,
  open decimal,
  high decimal,
  low decimal,
  close decimal,
  volume decimal,
  UNIQUE (code, ddate)

);

\copy stock_data_tmp FROM STDIN WITH CSV;

INSERT INTO stock_data
  SELECT code, to_date(date, 'YYYYMMDD'), open, high, low, close, volume 
  FROM stock_data_tmp;

DROP TABLE stock_data_tmp;
```

An example csv file looks like this

```
AAA,20140102,21.195,21.24,1.16,1.215,607639
BBB,20140102,23.29,2.29,2.17,2.26,1863
CCC,20140102,61.34,0.345,0.34,0.34,112700
DDD,20140102,509.1,50.11,50.09,50.11,409863
```

From the shell I try:

```
cat /path/to/20140102.txt | psql -d my_db_name -f ~/path/to/script/update_stock_data.sql
```

But it gives me this error:

```
psql:/path/to/script/update_stock_data.sql:22: ERROR:  missing data for column "date"
CONTEXT:    COPY stock_data_tmp, line 1: ""
```

**However**, if in my script I change the COPY command to:

```
\copy stock_data_tmp FROM '/path/to/20140102.txt' WITH csv;
```

... and simply call

```
psql -d my_db_name -f ~/path/to/script/update_stock_data.sql
```

it succeeds.

Why am I getting this error when using `cat` and `STDIN`, and *not* when using the file PATH?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because if you use `-f`, `COPY` will try to read from that file and not from stdin.

Comment: Where did you get his information? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @meyer1994 Probably not in that detail, but you can figure it out easily by trial and error or by reading the source.

Comment: Yes, yes. I tested as soon as I saw your command and it worked. I just wanted to know where did you find out about it. Trial and error?

Comment: @meyer1994 Yes, if memory serves.